# David Williams: Linearity of Expectation on infinite sums?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation

Consider this proof of the completeness of $L^p$ and the step highlighted:

[image]

It is my understanding that, implicit in that step, is that , because expectation is a linear operation (which i understand) $$ \forall N \in \mathbb{N}: \ \sum_{n=1}^N E |X_{k_{n+1}} - X_{k_{n}}| =  E \big \{ \sum_{n=1}^N |X_{k_{n+1}} - X_{k_{n}}| \big \}  $$

then it  follows that

$$\sum_1^{\infty} E { |X_{k_{n+1}} - X_{k_{n}}| } =  E \big \{ \sum_1^{\infty} |X_{k_{n+1}} - X_{k_{n}}| \big \}   $$

But is this 'obvious' or does it require a proof ?

Comment: To remember (and this is probably mentioned by Williams somewhere): the identity $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(Y_n)=E\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty Y_n\right)$$ is **always valid** for **nonnegative** random variables $(Y_n)$, and holds in $[0,+\infty]$. This is a consequence of Fubini theorem for nonnegative functions, for the product measure $\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\delta_n\right)\otimes P$ on $\mathbb N\times \Omega$.

Comment: This provides me with another way of looking at it - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the linearity of the expectation, we have

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{n=1}^N |X_{k_{n+1}}-X_{k_n}| \right) = \sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{E}(|X_{k_{n+1}}-X_{k_n}|).$$

Since $\mathbb{E}(|X_{k_{n+1}}-X_{k_n}|) \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, this implies

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{n=1}^N |X_{k_{n+1}}-X_{k_n}| \right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(|X_{k_{n+1}}-X_{k_n}|) \qquad \text{for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$.} \tag{1}$$

On the other hand, it follows from the monotone convergence theorem that

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |X_{k_{n+1}}-X_{k_n}| \right) = \sup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E} \left(\sum_{n=1}^N |X_{k_{n+1}}-X_{k_n}|\right) \tag{2}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |X_{k_{n+1}}-X_{k_n}| \right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(|X_{k_{n+1}}-X_{k_n}|).$$

Since the right-hand side is bounded by $\sum_{n \geq 1} 2^{-n}$, this proves that the expectation on the left-hand side is finite.

Comment: many thanks for your help

Comment: @user3203476 You are welcome.